# Refining the stance on computing questions

Tags: discussion, software

Earlier today I asked a question ([Mixed Effects Models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/using-mixed-effects-modelling-to-estimate-and-compare-variability)) and received a response. I want to post follow-up question that asks for R code to achieve the solution provided by the response, but is this type of solicitation appropriate for this site, or better left to stackoverflow?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using google's service to provide links to the qn? Ideally, you should simply link to the question directly using the editor provided.

Comment: Ah, I use it simply because the urls here are rather long and I know some dislike long urls that break up text. Has url shortening already been meta-decided as bad? If so let me know and I'll expand all the links.

Comment: See my edit to see how you need not use long urls.

Comment: Ah, you know I hadn't seen the link function in the editor. I'm too used to plain-text! Fixed in my other post now too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, asking for full fledged R code for your context is inappropriate. The ideal statistical computing question would be something along the following lines:

- Explain model context / your goals etc
- Give some minimal example of R code that you are having trouble with
- Ask your question about the code (e.g., bugs, slow code etc that you have)

Comment: +1 That's a good summary.

Answer (score 3):

Your question on Mixed effects models is fine. As for a follow-up question it would be OK to ask what R packages are available to fit your model. More than likely, someone would post some code that you could use.

When a questionnaire asks for a fully worked solution the OP can come across a bit lazy.